# WP7 how to know when popup shows up?

Tags: windows-phone-7, popup, show, detect

I'm using popup to show my user control. I want to detect when the popup is REALLY shown up on the screen, then I show the progress bar, do some work, then hide the progress bar

```
MyDialog dialog = new MyDialog();
myPopup.Child = dialog;
myPopup.IsOpen = true;

dialog.progressLoading.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
Thread.Sleep(3000)
dialog.progressLoading.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
```

However, I realize that `IsOpen = true` doesnot show the popup instantly. The fact is that I must wait 3 seconds for it to show up.

How to know when popup shows up ?

Comment: Can you post code for the MyDialog class! Can't know what takes so long to initialize dialog.

Comment: @MasterChief MyDialog is just a user control. The popup takes 3 seconds to show up because I call Thread.Sleep(3000). What I want to demonstrate here is that popup doesnot show instantly !